# 2 links to different paths within 1 image box

Tags: website-design, navigation

Similar to say images on the CNN or USA today home page. I have a slider display of images that will look like a bunch of small snapshots of reports. The reports will have the report name underneath that acts like a standard link. Clicking on the link will open the report. My issue is we have 2 behaviors we want to trigger. One is opening the report, the other is opening a lightbox that contains the report details. I have an image to represent the opening of that secondary action. (translation issues prevent the use of text links)

While there is a hand indicator and tool tip on both paths (report name link, and open report details), visually it isn't prominent that there are 2 actions. The icon for the secondary path (open report details) visually over powers the desired primary action - to open the report. I need a way to visually show the user there are 2 different paths. I can't use dimming the image, and I can't use strong colors - I have to stay within the color guidelines of company. 
I can't use another icon since longer term we will have more icons. I have the secondary path (icon) in a faint color and at the bottom right of the whole container - out of the way from the image and report name. I have a container for both the image, the report name link and the icon that represents the report details popup. The container outlines in a different color when that report is selected.

After a few sample reviews, people are not clicking on the link or the image - they are assuming the little gray icon is the way to open the report. Thus my issue - the main desired path is not visually strong enough despite have the most real estate.

Any suggestion for making the primary action more prominent?

Comment: Welcome to UX! Please add a screenshot or mockup as it will greatly increase your chances of getting an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Placing the icon at the top right of the image might work. You need to disassociate the icon from the report name, and putting some distance between them is a good way. You can also put some kind of a visual separator between the two - maybe even something as simple as a | .

Answer (score 0):

Would help a lot if you could provide a screenshot of the layout you're describing.

If it's possible, I would recommend putting an information icon ("i") in the top-left corner (top-right might feel like a close icon position). Similar to how CNN have placed the "play" icon to signify video content (see pic).

[image]

Also, what is the reason for having the secondary action (the report details overlay)? And what is this information that this provides to the user?

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

An example: the grid view Zappos lets you click to view the item on a new page, or click the "Quick View" button (that appears on hover) for a lightbox-style view.

You could also try teaching people what certain icons/buttons/links do with a [Tipsy](http://onehackoranother.com/projects/jquery/tipsy/)-style tooltip instead of browser-default tooltips that only appear after a delayed hover.

A screenshot or mockup of your application would definitely help.